# OpenMP: run two functions in parallel, each by half of thread pool

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I have a CPU consuming function `do_long` that I need to run on two different datasets.

```
do_long(data1);
do_long(data2);

do_long() {
#pragma omp for
    for(...) {
        // do proccessing
    }
}
```

I have N threads available (depends on machine). How to tell OpenMP that I want that both `do_long`
functions are run in parallel, and N/2 threads should perform the loop in first `do_long` and another N/2 should process second `do_long`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach is to do it using nested parallelism:

```
void do_long(int threads) {
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threads)
    for(...) {
        // do proccessing
    }
}


int main(){
    omp_set_nested(1);

    int threads = 8;
    int sub_threads = (threads + 1) / 2;

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        int i = omp_get_thread_num();

        if (i == 0){
            do_long(data1, sub_threads);
        }
        if (i == 1 || omp_get_num_threads() != 2){
            do_long(data2, sub_threads);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```